how to upgrade unsupported ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10
I haven’t been able to update Ubbuntu from 23.04 to 23.10 for several months, I tried changing servers
serg@serg-HP-Laptop-14s-fq0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                         
Hit:4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease               
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease                
Err:8 https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ub... jammy InRelease                 
  403  Forbidden [IP: 3.164.240.43 443]
Ign:9 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/lunar pgadmin4 InRelease
Err:10 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/lunar pgadmin4 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ub.../dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 3.164.240.43 443]
E: The repository 'https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ub... jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/lunar pgadmin4 Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

if I try to upgrade dist with software updater, i get meessage with same text

Please fresh install 24.04

Do do-release-upgrade -d

The issue is that you have been trying to upgrade from a version that stopped being supported months ago which means the repos get turned off / archived.  You can try the upgrade from an unsupported release:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

same problem
E:The repository
'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/lunar pgadmin4
Release' no longer has a Release file., W:Updating from such a
repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and
user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch
https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ub.../dists/jammy/InRelease 403
Forbidden [IP: 3.164.240.24 443], E:The repository
'https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ub... jammy InRelease' is not
signed.
Restoring original system state

It is common for maintained sources to drop support after a release goes EOL.  Ubuntu 23.04 has been EOL for some time; refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/  thus the error with https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/  Maintain your system & plan release-upgrades before EOL... and don't forget mantic or 23.10 which you'll release-upgrade to reaches its EOL next month !
